# PDO update error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make a UPDATE script for a wargame that I'm making in PHP. 
Here is the script which contains the error:

```
if(($donnees_reglages['maj_attaques']+86390) <= time())
{
    $selection_joueurs = $bdd->query('SELECT id FROM membres');
    while($donnees_joueurs = $selection_joueurs->fetch())
    {
        $maj_medailles= "";
        $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO medailles(pseudo_medaille) VALUES('.$donnees_joueurs['id'].')');
        /* Médailles pour les ressources */
        $selection_pieces = $bdd->query('SELECT MAX(piece_or) AS or_max, 
                                                MAX(pierre) AS pierre_max 
                                           FROM ressources 
                                          WHERE pseudo_ressource='.$donnees_joueurs['id'].'');
        $donnees_pieces = $selection_pieces->fetch();
        $selection_pieces->closeCursor();

        //Or
        if($donnees_pieces['or_max'] >= 10000)
        {
            $maj_medailles .= 'aisance_economique=aisance_economique+1';
        }

        if($donnees_pieces['or_max'] >= 30000)
        {
            if(!empty($maj_medailles))
                $maj_medailles .= ', ';
            $maj_medailles .= 'richesse_economique=richesse_economique+1';
        }

        //Pierre
        if($donnees_pieces['pierre_max'] >= 10000)
        {
            if(!empty($maj_medailles))
                $maj_medailles .= ', ';
            $maj_medailles .= 'producteur_local=producteur_local+1';
        }

        if($donnees_pieces['pierre_max'] >= 30000)
        {
            if(!empty($maj_medailles))
                $maj_medailles .= ', ';
            $maj_medailles .= 'producteur_national=producteur_national+1';
        }

        /* Médailles pour les forteresses */
        $selection_max_forteresses = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb_id 
                                                    FROM forteresses 
                                                   WHERE membre_forteresse='.$donnees_joueurs['id'].'');
        $donnees_max_forteresses = $selection_max_forteresses->fetch();
        $selection_max_forteresses->closeCursor();

        $joueurs_forteresses[] = $donnees_joueurs['id'];
        $nb_forteresses[] = $donnees_max_forteresses['nb_id'];
        if($donnees_max_forteresses['nb_id'] == 2)
        {
            if(!empty($maj_medailles))
                $maj_medailles .= ', ';
            $maj_medailles .= 'vassal=vassal+1';
        }

        if($donnees_max_forteresses['nb_id'] >= 5)
        {
            if(!empty($maj_medailles))
                $maj_medailles .= ', ';
            $maj_medailles .= 'seigneur=seigneur+1';
        }

        /* Médailles pour les recherches */
        $selection_recherches = $bdd->query('SELECT * 
                                               FROM recherches 
                                              WHERE pseudo_recherche='.$donnees_joueurs['id'].'');
        $donnees_recherches = $selection_recherches->fetch();
        $selection_recherches->closeCursor();
        if($donnees_recherches['archer'] == 1 && 
           $donnees_recherches['soldat'] == 1 && 
           $donnees_recherches['cavalier'] == 1 && 
           $donnees_recherches['monstre'] == 1 && 
           $donnees_recherches['heros'] == 1)
        {
            if($donnees_recherches['colon'] == 1 && $donnees_recherches['transfert'])
            {
                if(!empty($maj_medailles))
                    $maj_medailles .= ', ';
                $maj_medailles .= 'genie_militaire=genie_militaire+1';
            }
            else
            {
                if(!empty($maj_medailles))
                    $maj_medailles .= ', ';
                $maj_medailles .= 'conquistador=conquistador+1';
            }
        }

        $bdd->exec("UPDATE medailles 
                       SET $maj_medailles 
                     WHERE pseudo_medaille=".$donnees_joueurs['id']."") or exit(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
    }
    $selection_joueurs->closeCursor();
```

And here is my error when I'm running the code:

> Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE pseudo_medaille=1' at line 1 ) 1

Please help me. I have searched everywhere :( !?
(Sorry for my possible bad English, it's not my native language).

Comment: So why exactly did you move into PDO if you're not using any of the good features it provides you with ? You're wide open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Please, read up on how to use PDO placeholders properly. Using string concatenation is **extremely** dangerous.

Comment: I'm trying to begin with PDO. Isn't it a good idea?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this kind of questions are considered offtopic on this site. Nobody cares though, but just to let you know.

Comment: @EdouardLibion I suggest you to drop whatever tutorial you're following right now and find one that uses the best practice of it. [For example you should be using prepared statement when needed as a minimum requirement.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Ok, thanks you, I'll remake everythings.

Comment: @EdouardLibion [here is a tutorial on it if u prefer rather then the PHP manual.](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

Comment: As other comments mentioned you'd better to learn PDO a little bit more. For your syntax error, probably `$maj_medailles` is not set as you may have expected so it leaves an empty string
.